# AES ENCRYPT JAVA and ASP .Net

Tags: java, asp.net, aes

I try to encrypt a String using AES Encrypt for different platform. I can successfully execute it PHP and Java. But when i try it in ASP .NET its giving different Value.
JAVA Code

```
String input="Text";
String key="1234567891234567";
    byte[] crypted = null;
            try {
                SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
                crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                throw exception;
            }
            return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(crypted));
```

ASP Code:

```
AesManaged tdes = new AesManaged();
 tdes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567891234567");
                    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    ICryptoTransform crypt = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
                    byte[] plain = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text);
                    byte[] cipher = crypt.TransformFinalBlock(plain, 0,plain.Length);
                    encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipher);
```

What i am doing wrong in second part?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two possible problems with your code examples. I can't currently test the ASP code, so this is a theory at the moment:

1. In your Java code you call `getBytes()` on two occasions and fail to supply a charset. This means you will use your default platform charset. Conversely, in your ASP code you specify UTF-8. I would strongly recommend you change your Java code to `getBytes("UTF-8")` to force it to match.
2. In a similar vein, you return your base64 result using the following code:

   ```
   return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(crypted));
   ```

   I'm assuming this is commons-code `Base64`? If so, the `encodeBase64` method returns UTF-8 bytes, yet you are relying again on your default platform charset when interpreting the bytes into a string. Either change this to:

   ```
   return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(crypted), "UTF-8");
   ```

   or use the convenience method:

   ```
   return Base64.encodeBase64String(crypted);
   ```

If your platform's default encoding is not UTF-8, then the above errors may be causing your problems. If your default encoding *is* UTF-8, then the changes above will ensure your code is more portable (but probably won't fix your problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get exact same result as your `JAVA` code.

Visual Basic Code:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Shared Function encrypt(data As String, key As String)
    Dim tdes As AesManaged = New AesManaged()
    tdes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    Dim crypt As ICryptoTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor()
    Dim plain As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
    Dim cipher As Byte() = crypt.TransformFinalBlock(plain, 0, plain.Length)
    Dim encryptedText As String = Convert.ToBase64String(cipher)
    Return encryptedText
End Function
```